# Li-Yorke sensitivity Vs Li-Yorke dense chaos

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, chaos

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $X*X$ its cartesian product, and $A$ a subset of $X*X$.

Are the following two properties the same, or e.g. one is stronger than the other?

1. $A$ is dense and residual in $X*X$
2. For every $x \in X$ and every neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$, there is a point $y \in U_x$ (with $y \neq x$) for which the pair $(x, y) \in A$

This relation lies at the ground of the distinction between *dense Li-Yorke chaos*
and *Li-Yorke sensitivity* as proposed [by Akin & Kolyada](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0951-7715/16/4/313)

Comment: The second property surely does not imply being residual, since it is satisfied by $A=X\times X$. The first implies the second just because $A$ is dense, meagerness is not needed

Comment: Assuming all the occurrences of $x$ in 2 really refer to the same point, both implications have counterexamples with $X$ being the circle $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. The set $\{(x,y):x\neq 0\}$ is dense and residual but doesn't satisfy 2 for $x=0$. The set $\{(x,y):(\exists n\in\mathbb N)\,(x-y=1/n)\}$ satisfies 2 but is not dense (and thus not residual either).